# NodeJS crashing when new file copied or replaced/overwrite file in particular location

Tags: reactjs, node.js, docker, containers, node-modules

I have a NodeJS application developed and running successfully and my NodeJS application is a static application that reads the data from files and represents the data to react UI, data files are in JSON format and files are located in the path
`<NodeJS APP root>/src/data/<JSON files>`

I have created a docker image from it and am not copying the data files during the docker build and created volume and mount on docker container path `/app/src/data/`.
whenever there is any change in files I update the JSON files outside of appcode and replace/overwrite the JSON files, whenever I do that, the NodeJS app crashes or the docker container restarts. Below is the error when container restarts

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../data/main_data' in '/app/src/scenes/mainStatus'
ERROR in ./src/scenes/mainStatus/index.jsx 14:0-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../data/main_data' in '/app/src/scenes/mainStatus'

webpack compiled with 1 error
Compiling...
Compiled successfully!
webpack compiled successfully
```

Can anyone help to resolve this issue, I don't want the container to be restarted whenever there is any change in the file/files location at path `/app/src/data/<JSON>`

Comment: If the code isn't in your image, what is?  If it's pretty much just the unmodified `node` image, can you install Node directly on your host system and not involve Docker at all?

Comment: apart from JSON files, the rest of the code is copied to docker images and the main goal is to run this on a POD

Comment: Like in Kubernetes?  The cluster can't access your local system and updating a Deployment generally deletes and recreates Pods, so the restart issue you're describing wouldn't happen.

Comment: From just the error message it's a little hard to tell what might be going on, though.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?